# Scope open tag only in VSCode/Textmate HTML Grammar

Tags: visual-studio-code, textmate

I'm trying to edit a theme to style the opening HTML tags, without using the same style on closing tag.  EG make italic like this:

```html
<***div*** class="my-divvy">Here is <***strong***>strong</**strong**> text tags in HTML.</**div**>
```

There is `entity.name.tag.html` scope, but that will capture both the open (`<div>`) AND closing (`</div>`) tags, which I do not want.  There is also `meta.tag.structure.div.start.html entity.name.tag`, replacing `div` for every HTML tag, but that would make a long array which I am trying to avoid.

How can I edit the language definition (`html.tmLanguage.json` file) to provide an open-tag-only scope so I can add a simple rule to the theme please?

Bonus: similar issue with JSX; who to scope only the open tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` command, you will see that there is a separate scope for start and end tags, like:

`meta.tag.structure.div.start.html`
`meta.tag.structure.div.end.html`

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any **generic** start and end tag scope - you have to include the element name - like `div` or `span` in each one.  So, this works for the **div's and span's ending tags** in the `settings.json` file:

```
    "scope": "meta.tag.structure.div.start.html entity.name.tag, meta.tag.inline.span.start.html entity.name.tag",
```

but you need an entry like `"meta.tag.structure.div.start.html entity.name.tag"` for each tag name you want to support - swapping `div` out each time.

And I had to include `entity.name.tag` within each tag's scope to get it to work.

Try this **in your theme file**:

```
"scope": [
  "meta.tag.structure.div.start.html entity.name.tag", 
  "meta.tag.inline.span.start.html entity.name.tag",
  "etc.",
  "etc.",
]
```

Comment: > "Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any generic start and end tag scope - you have to include the element name - like div or span in each one."

Sorry I noticed that, but didn't add it to my OP.  Yes, I am trying to avoid making my *color-theme.json too verbose by adding 30 scopes. I want to edit or supersede my html.tmLanguage.json file to add an extra scope rule so I have to add only 6 or so lines in my theme file. This also won't work for JSX (XML?). So I updated my question.

Thanks for fast reply though!